# How do I modify an AWS EC2 purchased reserved instance from t2.small to t2.micro

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS EC2 instance, initial configuration was a t2.small in which I purchased a t2.small reserved instance. after running the instance for 12 months, I have down scaled due to a reduction in my server requirement to a t2.micro. How do I modify the t2.small purchased reserved instance to a t2.micro.
I notice that the scaled down instance is still being billed as a t2.small instance.

Answer (score 0):

> "I notice that the scaled down instance is still being billed as a
> t2.small instance."

No, that's not how reservations work. You reserved a t2.small, and you are being charged for a t2.small, whether you use one or not. You are **also** now being charged for a t2.micro. Reservations are not tied to a specific instance, they are simply a reservation of a specific amount of compute power.

You can [convert or exchange your instance reservation](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/reserved-instances/), depending on which type of reservation you created. However you would only be able to convert a t2.small into two t2.micro reservations. You are still going to be paying the same either way. You made a commitment to pay for a certain amount of compute usage on AWS, in order to obtain a pricing discount, now they are going to make you honor that commitment.

If you have a standard reservation you may be able to [sell it](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/reserved-instances/marketplace/) to another AWS customer. Otherwise it would probably be cheaper for you to continue using a t2.small instance until your reservation expires.